# Xamarin form-UWP - black cell showing before data is visible on fast scrolling of list

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

When i scroll the list fast, each cell appears as black before data is loaded.If i scroll slowly data black cells won't appear. This behavior is happening only for Xamarin UWP project. Please find the below image for reference.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the issue by writing custom ViewCell and by making use of native datatemplate. Now there is no black cells on fast scrolling. I am posting my answer so that someone may find it useful.

For eg: If you have a list of names to be displayed follow:

First add custom viewcell as follows

```
        public class CustomViewCell : ViewCell
       {
        public static readonly BindableProperty NameProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create("Name", typeof(string), typeof(CustomViewCell), "");

        public string Name
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
        }

       }
```

Now add the ListView in XAML as follows:

```
            <ListView 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Products}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <custom:CustomViewCell  Name="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Then you have to write the DateTemplate style in App.xaml of UWP project as follows:

```
        <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomTemplate">
            <Grid Padding="10">
                <TextBlock  Foreground="#333333" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

Finally write a CustomRenderer to replace the native viewcell to our our ListView.

```
    public class CustomViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
    public override Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate GetTemplate(Cell cell)
    {
        return App.Current.Resources["CustomTemplate"] as Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate;
    }
    }
```

Now list works perfectly without any black cell rendering issue.

Comment: Hi @Renjith, still that black screen is flickered in the listview using the custom view cell. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem with your code. When you scroll too fast the system doesn't have time to render the cells as quickly as you are scrolling, so the black cell appears.

Comment: luccas-clezar Yes thats right. This issue is happening only UWP. Is there any to overcome this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so. I tried several ways of increasing performance (like trying to remove the bindings and do the changes of the cell in the PropertyChanged or BindingContextChanged) but I didn't notice any performance increase.

Comment: Hi have fixed the issue by customizing the ViewCell. I have written the customrenderer to fix the issue. Now there is no black cells on fast scrolling. I have added my answer below.